# Print tree node and all of it's childs efficiently

Tags: c, tree, tree-traversal, multiway-tree

I am trying to make a function that would print a node and all of its children but I am trying to make it efficient and also recursive. But it doesn't really work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE    100

typedef struct tree {
    int value;
    struct tree *child, *sibling, *parent;
} *Tree;

Tree initTree(int value) {
    Tree root = malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
    root->value = value;
    root->parent = NULL;
    root->child = NULL;
    root->sibling = NULL;
    return root;
}

void drawTreeHelper(Tree tree, FILE* stream) {
    Tree tmp;
    if (tree == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    fprintf(stream, "    %ld[label=\"%d\", fillcolor=red]\n", (intptr_t) tree, tree->value);
    tmp = tree->child;

    while (tmp != NULL) {
        fprintf(stream, "    %ld -> %ld \n", (intptr_t) tree, (intptr_t) tmp);
        drawTreeHelper(tmp, stream);
        tmp = tmp->sibling;
    }
}

void drawTree(Tree tree, char *fileName) {
    FILE* stream = fopen("test.dot", "w");
    char buffer[SIZE];
    fprintf(stream, "digraph tree {\n");
    fprintf(stream, "    node [fontname=\"Arial\", shape=circle, style=filled, fillcolor=yellow];\n");
    if (tree == NULL)
        fprintf(stream, "\n");
    else if (!tree->child)
        fprintf(stream, "    %ld [label=\"%d\"];\n", (intptr_t) tree, tree->value);
    else
        drawTreeHelper(tree, stream);
    fprintf(stream, "}\n");
    fclose(stream);
    sprintf(buffer, "dot test.dot | neato -n -Tpng -o %s", fileName);
    system(buffer);
}

Tree uniteTries(Tree child, Tree parent)
{
    if (parent)
    {
        if (!parent->child) parent->child = child;
        else
        {
            Tree iter = parent->child;
            while (iter->sibling) iter = iter->sibling;
            iter->sibling = child;
        }
    }
    return parent;
}

Tree uniteForest(Tree root, Tree *forest, int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if (forest[i]) root = uniteTries(forest[i], forest[i]->parent);
    }
    root = forest[0];
    return root;
}

void printParentChildRec(Tree root)
{
    if(!root) return;
    printf("%d ", root->value);

    printParentChildRec(root->sibling);
    printParentChildRec(root->child);
}

int main() {
    int i;
    char buffer[SIZE];
    Tree *forest = malloc(6 * sizeof(Tree));
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        forest[i] = initTree(i);
    }

    forest[1]->parent = forest[0];
    forest[2]->parent = forest[0];
    forest[3]->parent = forest[0];
    forest[4]->parent = forest[1];
    forest[5]->parent = forest[1];

    Tree root = uniteForest(root, forest, 6);

    printParentChildRec(root);

    drawTree(root, "tree.png");

    return 0;
}
```

This code will provide you with a verifiable example and here's what I tried to do:

```
void printParentChildRec(Tree root) {
    if (!root)
        return;
    printf("%d ", root->value);

    printParentChildRec(root->sibling);
    printParentChildRec(root->child);
}
```

The results I am getting is just `0 1 2 3 4 5` which is all the nodes,  but I want to print something like this:

```
0 1 2 3
1 4 5
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems in your code:

- You hide pointers behind typedefs, this is confusing for readers of your code and often leads to programming errors.
- You print `intptr_t` values with `%ld`, which is undefined behavior on platforms where `intptr_t` is not an alias for `long` and has a different size, such as Windows 64-bit. There is no specific `printf` format for this type, you should either recast the value as `(long)(intptr_t)tree` or `(long long)(intptr_t)tree` and use `%lld`, or their unsigned versions or use the `%p` format with `(void *)tree`.
- the result you expect is not produced as text, but some form of graphics rendering which is difficult to analyse from the code. Producing textual output first would be easier to debug.

Here are more problems in your code:

- in `main()`, `Tree root = uniteForest(root, forest, 6);` passes undefined variable `root` to `uniteForest`.
- argument `root` in `Tree uniteForest(Tree root, Tree *forest, int n)` is never used, it is used only to store temporary results. You should just remove the argument and simplify the code as:

  ```
  Tree uniteForest(Tree *forest, int n) {
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
          if (forest[i])
              uniteTries(forest[i], forest[i]->parent);
      }
      return forest[0];
  }
  ```
- `main` only prints the root of the tree, hence the value of `forest[0]` and those of its descendants recursively. You instead want to print the value of the node and that of its immediate children, **then** recurse for each child.

Here is a corrected version:

```
void printParentChildRec(Tree node) {
    if (node) {
        printf("%d ", node->value);
        for (Tree child = node->child; child; child = child->sibling) {
            printf("%d ", child->value);
        }
        printf("\n");
        for (Tree child = node->child; child; child = child->sibling) {
            printParentChildRec(child);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3
1 4 5
4
5
2
3
```

Comment: Hello, sorry, but this is just a fixation of mine with "hiding the pointer behind the typdef" also, the image generated is just for you to get some visual output. The original output would be if you would just call the function i give below.

Comment: @A.Cretan: do you really insist on hiding pointers behind typedefs? C is not java, hiding pointers behind typedefs is what java does for all objects, but it does not have true pointers, so it is not confusing. When you start using pointers to your typedefed pointers in C, things tend to become messy. That's just my opinion, but a widely admitted one.

Comment: I understand your opinion but I really don't think this is the subject here, the point here is that: the code works, the problem statement is up, I am just trying to get some help and get my head around that, those things are pretty minor things behind the real problem that is asked, I truly understand what you are saying, but the code is running and it works well. I hope you can understand me and see my point of view here, thus your answer shouldn't really be an answer but rather a comment

Comment: @A.Cretan: I'll grant you that the first point is an opinion, the second point is real, yet minor and the third point is a request for more information. Your code does not produce the posted output, which might explain why you don't get more precise answers.

Comment: Beucase the functino is not called :-?? in the first code?? you mist aswell just copy it from the bottom paste it into the other one and call it in main???

Comment: @A.Cretan: I'm afraid I'm unable to help you here, I have given you hints on how to investigate, I am not going to debug your code for you, I don't have the `neato` nor `dot` utilities to display your tree. Simplify the problem, find the solution, then add features.

Comment: Here, for you. Check the output of the given code now. No need to "debug my code", now you just have to run it and see the output. Now let the real question be answered and please be a little more versatile.

Comment: @A.Cretan:  Here is your answer. The problem is indeed in `printParentChildRec`, your goal was not so clear, I think I got it right now.

Comment: Can you explain a little what you did there?

Comment: @A.Cretan: I print the node value and iterate over the list of children to print their node value, then I iterate over the list of children to recursively print their lists. The result is different from what you expect because the tree is traversed depth first.

Answer (score 0):

I think your unite trees function is the problem here. I ran this code with my debugger and this is what it looks like from the root

This is the root as inputted into the print function after the unite trees method:

[image]

Can you tell me what you are trying to achieve here and maybe I can help you out!

Comment: Yeah, I know this is what it looks like. This is how it should look like. It is specified in the question what I want to achieve: a recursive function that will print the "value" of the current node and also all the "values" of it's children.